# C# functions on generic numeric primitives

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, invoke, primitive-types

I routinely want to do generalized functions on "numbers", whether those numbers are ints or doubles or floats or bytes. Just do your arithmetic, adding ints to get ints or duobles to get double, and then return [that]. Unfortunately, C# doesn't seem to have a base "IAddable" interface that all numbers implement. E.g.

```
public static Val Sum<Val>(this IEnumerable<Val> vals) where Val: IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    Val output = default;
    foreach(Val val in vals)
    {
        if(typeof(Val) == typeof(int))
            output = (Val)((int)output + (int)val);
        else if(typeof(Val) == typeof(double))
            output = (Val)((double)output + (double)val);
        else if(typeof(Val) == typeof(byte))
            output = (Val)((byte)output + (byte)val);
        else 
            throw new Exception("Bad type.");
    }
    return output;
}
```

So, 1) That sucks. I'd rather restrict the function's use than throw an exception when somebody tries Int16 or whatever. 2) It doesn't even compile. "Cannot convert type 'Val' to 'int'."

Is there a "TryCast", like some have "TryParse"? How do I convince C# to just chill and cast what I tell it to cast?

Comment: Numeric types already have this polymorphic ability.  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What you're probably looking for is either `T`, `object` or `dynamic`, not `Val`

Comment: There's no reason for such code. In fact, LINQ already provides a `Sum`, so what's the problem? What is `Val` ? Are you trying to mix integers and floats in the same collection?

Comment: You should not user generics to implement a method that only supports a small number of specific types.  Just make overloads for each of the types you wish to support.

Comment: Altought there is nothing implemented yet, there is a [discussion about adding shapes as a feature](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/164). If one day that is approved and get implemented, you could declare that you generic type has a shape that has the `+` operator and return `output+val`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sorry for the dupe. I do understand that my specific example above is in Linq; I was writing a more complicated function in real life. :)